# How to handle unnecessary recompositions within if-else statement in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm using if-else state in jetpck compose project to compose UI. It working fine as it needed but the problem is that even if the first if statements are to be passed it shouls a flicker effect of that ui as well and then show the final ui that is supposed to be shown. For example we have `AccessInfo()` and `MediaScreen()` now in if statement these are to be composed in sequence wihtout any flickering or recompositon.

Here what i have tried

```
@Composable
fun PermissionHandler(
    viewModel: HomeViewModel,
    state: HomeUIState
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val permissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions)
    var selectedUri: Uri?
    val safLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedUri = result.data?.data
                if (selectedUri != null) {
                    if (selectedUri.toString() == "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia") {
                        viewModel.saveSAFValue(true)
                        context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                            selectedUri!!,
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    if (!permissionsState.allPermissionsGranted) {
        AccessInfo(
            accessModel = AccessModel(
                lottieComposition = R.raw.gallery_permission,
                title = R.string.permission_required,
                description = R.string.permission_read_and_write,
                buttonText = R.string.allow_access_button
            ),
            onAllowButtonClick = { permissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest() })
    } else if (!state.isSAFGranted) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            .apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
            }
        AccessInfo(
            accessModel = AccessModel(
                lottieComposition = R.raw.gallery_permission,
                title = R.string.folder_access_required,
                description = R.string.folder_access_required_desc,
                buttonText = R.string.allow_folder_access_button,
                linkText = R.string.why_we_need_this,
                popUpContent = R.array.SAF_requirement_details,
                popUpButtonText = R.string.allow_folder_access_button
            ),
            isPopupEnabled = true,
            onAllowButtonClick = { safLauncher.launch(intent) })
    } else {
        MediaScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and also show how you initialize your `permissionState` variable. It is possible that the flickering occurs because the variable is initially set to value and then changed after a few milliseconds.

Comment: @BenjyTec I have edited the question to show the full composable file code. Please check it.

Comment: Are you adding all `permissions` list values at once or to you add them subsequently to the list?

Comment: I'm adding the permissions at once.

Comment: Where are you calling the PermissionHandler method? Maybe the place where you call them is changing and causes recomposition.

Comment: Its called in the same file in top level composable. Here is is `@Composable fun PermissionScreen(){  PermissionHandler() }`

Answer (score 0):

Compose has [movableContentOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#movableContentOf(kotlin.Function0)) for such use-case. If it's called once in different locations, same view will be reused - just make sure you're handling parameters change in `AccessInfo` correctly.

```kotlin
val accessInfo = movableContentOf { isPopupEnabled: Boolean, onAllowButtonClick: () -> Unit ->
    AccessInfo(
        accessModel = /*...*/,
        isPopupEnabled = isPopupEnabled,
        onAllowButtonClick = onAllowButtonClick
    )
}

if (!permissionsState.allPermissionsGranted) {
    accessInfo(
        false,
        { permissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest() }
    )
} else if (!state.isSAFGranted) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        .apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
    accessInfo(
        true,
        { safLauncher.launch(intent) }
    )
}
```

Comment: OKay . I tried your code this way https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rw7XlyEWsEDpAdyof9lRv70MhuFC-eky/view?usp=sharing but its not working also.

Comment: @CODAR747 have you tried it in my way? in your case you're using different `AccessInfo` calls, so I'm not surprised that it creates different views

Comment: Tried exact similar to your way its not working though.

Comment: @CODAR747 please clarify your question by describing expected/actual behavior, perfectly with a video, and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)